# Should I address a trend in responses to my question?

Tags: discussion, editing

I asked a question which become a hot network question recently. There has been a large amount of people commenting.

There seems to be a small trend of people accusing the company I work for of being bad, or me for being inadequate somehow (I.E., inexperienced, unprofessional, and so forth.) in questions and comments.

I don’t want to engage these comments and questions, **but should I edit my question to clarify that I don’t think badly of my workplace or my managers and do not like response which encourage a negative view**? That we all have flaws and need to work to get along?

Or should I just ride it out and ignore the negativity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having read through the comments on there (most of which were deleted) I'm not really sure what you are referring to  - any updates you want to make should be edited into the question.

Feel free to flag comments, particularly those posted after this:

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat. – Jane S♦ 2 days ago

Which is not unclear about where extended discussion should go.

---

Also for what it's worth, this topic is going to spark a holy war amongst Hot Network Question readers for the same reasons why you posted it. A moderator can lock the post temporarily to wait out the HNQ timespan, too, if you want.

Comment: I appreciate the perspective. Having never been on HNQ, the attention on my question is uncomfortable even if appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, Interpersonal Skills.SE [has suggested](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2884/2309) that the association bonus not be included for the purposes of the "Comment Everywhere" privilege, which would hopefully decrease the number of comments added to Hot Network Questions by excluding those that aren't already active on the site.

Comment: @Thunderforge I've been wanting/suggesting that for _years_...

Comment: @ElysianFields Well, other people are at least suggesting it now too, so it's no longer just you (and at a site that has that problem even worse than Workplace.SE). Hopefully that means it's gaining traction.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, congratulations on your question making it to HNQ. Welcome to the league of elite users who have had the good fortune of having their question (or answer) making it to HNQ.

Now coming to your actual issue, remember [HNQ is entertainment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220099/202356). You would have noticed that most of those comments come from users who have 101 reputation (or close enough). These are users who have the association bonus by virtue of earning "trust on another site". They show up here from the HNQ sidebar, have their share of "entertainment" (while they are bored waiting for C++ code to compile or in a weekly status meeting), and will likely not return for a long time.

In other words, consider it to be a "working as designed" property of HNQ entertainment. You don't need to defend your question against anything. Just ignore those comments and move on.

Comment: Echoing my sentiment from a comment on another answer, I appreciate the perspective, and don’t feel pressured to respond to every comment and answer. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can edit the question to state you do not feel think badly the workplace.  But you do criticize management.

I found the question to be confusing, over formatted, and a bit of a rant.

There is not requirement to reply to comment.  If they are rude then flag and let the moderators deal with it.